# Database Properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, uniqueidentifier

There are multiple SQL Server instances on the company network, all are named uniquely, however, each one has the same database name, like ClientDB. I know there is a database ID for each one but I was wondering if there was a unique identifier that would work across instances? Now that I write this it sounds silly, how would a new instance know database names already out there?
I am asking because I am gathering information on all our databases like name, creator, size, last backed up, etc. into a table and it gets confusing because many records have the same database name. Perhaps there is an Instance ID or a  database GUID somewhere, or do I just need to keep track of both the instance and database name to identify a record? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a "machine name" and a "server name" property for SQL Server, maybe this is what you're looking for.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the database name with the "host". The host is also known as:

- "machine name", "hostname", "host name".
- "server" or "server name", "computer name".
- "box".
- the "vm" or "vm name".

Answer (score 0):

It's called `composite key`. Since the database name alone isn't enough to uniquely identify it among your assets, you need to bring additional attributes to the table.

- `@@server_name` to identify an instance of MS SQL Server on a box, along with the box name;
- `db_name()` or a select from `sys.databases` to get database name(s) on that instance.

Together they comprise a key sufficiently unique for most cases. Note however that you still might get collisions if:

- There are several AD domains in your network, and some servers have duplicate names in different domains. A bad network design decision by itself; I would try to switch from instance names to IP addresses here, or add the `default_domain()` function if your SQL Server versions support it;
- You have clustered SQL instances. Not a collision per se, rather a duplicate in your records; just make sure you don't use cluster nodes' names, or keep a separate list of clusters / AlwaysOn instances to work around this. Haven't actually checked this myself, might be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The [`service_broker_guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms166057(v=sql.105)) property assigned to each database (other than `master` and `model`) upon creation in SQL Server could satisfy your need. The `service_borker_guid` is a [Global Unique Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), otherwise known as a UUID.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) says the following about the chances that you will find two of the same value in, and out, of your network:

> While the probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is
>   close enough to zero to be negligible

The query below will grab the GUID you're looking for.

```
select @@servername as host_nm, name as db_nm, service_broker_guid
from master.sys.databases
where name in ('ClientDB')
```

**Output:**

```
+----------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| host_nm        | db_nm    | service_broker_guid                  |
+----------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| MY_SERVER_NAME | ClientDB | 9B7C1BF1-022D-423D-9780-88B555459868 |
+----------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152414/how-uniqueidentifier-in-sql-server-is-always-a-unique-value-globally) on the DBA site elaborates on GUID's if you want more detail on the subject.